# Capifony SSH Exception on windows - 998 error code

Tags: capistrano, ssh-keys, capifony, pageant

I am trying to setup Capifony to deploy on windows however when running `cap deploy` I get the following output.

**Spec**

- ruby 2.0.0p481
- capifony v2.7.0

**The error message**

```
servers: ["homestead.app"]
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: homestead.app (Net::SSH::Exception: Creation of file mapping failed with error: 998) connection failed for: homestead.app (Net::SSH::Exception: Creation of file mapping failed with error: 998)
```

If I close down pageant this issue goes away however I require pageant to load the ssh key for  the github repo as it required for doing a `git ls-remote` locally.

Any suggestions/workarounds?

**Related issues found**

- https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my issue by using an older version of ruby (Ruby 1.9.3-p545).